# Which method is used to get mail ids given in CC and BCC list in JavaMail?

Tags: java

I have created a java mail program to send mails. I have doubt regarding which method is used to get mail id which is given in CC and BCC list?. For To list i have used the below code.

Code :
MimeMessage mime = new MimeMessage(session);
mime.addFrom(bean.getFromAddress());

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Address[] copiedAddrs = mime.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC);
```

and this:

```
Address[] blindCopiedAddrs = mime.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC);
```